# Getting id of deleting document mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

can I somehow get the id of document which I want to delete in MongoDB and Node.js ?

```
router.post('/removeFriend/:id', async (req, res) => {

    await Friends.updateOne({
        user_id: req.params.id
    }, {
        $pull: { friends: req.body._id }
    })

    await Friends.updateOne({
        user_id: req.body._id
    }, {
        $pull: { friends: req.params.id }
    })

    await Chat.deleteOne({
        users: { $all: [req.body._id, req.params.id] }
    }).then(result => { console.log(result) })

    res.status(200).json("Friend removed.");
})
```

I want to delete also all messages where `chat_id` is the id of deleting chat, so I need this id. In result I can't get it...

Comment: I think you will have to get the document first, then delete it.

Comment: I have already found a solution - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongoose-findoneanddelete-function/